# Provider OraOLEDB.Oracle does not return right results for vba

Tags: vba, vb6, oracle11g, provider

I have this .xls vba code where I am trying to check record count and based on that decide further logic.

This vba was working fine with Provider = MSDAORA but when I changed to Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle this vba check query always return record count = 0

Every other queries which use OraOLEDB.Oracle works fine.

Attached here code.

Thanks in advance for pointing out problem here.

```
Public Function CheckJob(BusDate As String, JobName As String) As Boolean
Dim Cnt As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmdGetComp As New ADODB.Command   
Dim RecCount As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim StConn As String
Dim Sql As String

StConn = strETDDBConnStringADO()'This is connection string with all credentials
Set Cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmdGetComp = New ADODB.Command

Sql = "Select Count(*) from XYZ_DBO.TABLE_STATUS where BUSINESS_DATE='XXXXXX'"


With Cnt
.Open (StConn)

With cmdGetComp
    .ActiveConnection = Cnt ' Reference to a Connection object.
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = Sql
     Set rst = .Execute() ' Set the Recordset to the results of executing the query
End With

RecCount = rst(0)  'rst(0) always return value of 0 even if manual query have 1 record
.Close
End With
If RecCount > 0 Then   
CheckJob = True
Else
CheckJob = False
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Consider changing your title, it should accurately define your problem rather than being a statement that the DB is wrong. What's more likely, Oracle is wrong or you are?

Comment: What is the data type of the `BUSINESS_DATE` column?  Is it a `DATE`?  Or a `VARCHAR2`?  Are you comparing it to a date?  Or to a string?

Comment: Justin, BUSINESS_DATE is in DATE format and I recently tried code if I remove Business Date condition it works perfect so there is a problem the way I pass Business_date. Can you please one example and I think I should be fine.

Comment: I am supplying BusDate As String this as BUSINESS_DATE

Comment: @user973842 - What is `'XXXXXX'` in your query?  Is that a hard-coded string?  What format is that string in?  What is the time component of `BUSINESS_DATE`?  Are you guaranteed that the time component is midnight?

Comment: @JustinCave - 'XXXXXX' is BusDate formatted as 'dd-MMM-yyyy' which is declared as string. BUSINESS_DATE is just data type of DATE and no time associated with it on Oracle side.

Comment: @user973842 - An Oracle `DATE` always has a time component in addition to the day.  Are you guaranteed that the time component of `BUSINESS_DATE` is always midnight?  `MMM` is not a valid format mask in Oracle-- perhaps you mean `MON` as in `01-MAR-2013`?  The code that you posted doesn't appear to declare a string variable, it is hard-coded in the SQL statement.  Is there a variable in your actual code?  Are you actually using bind variables?  Or are you dynamically building the SQL statement without using bind variables?

Comment: @JustinCave , yes Oracle DATE is by default midnight. Problem is when I pass hard coded date that also does not work. For example in sql I pass BUSINESS_DATE='28-FEB-2013' still return 0 as oppose to when I manually query DB it return 10.

Comment: @user973842 - Are you saying that you are guaranteed that `BUSINESS_DATE` always has a time component of midnight?  Is your actual query using bind variables?  Or is it dynamically assembling the SQL statement?  Or is the string hard-coded in the SQL statement?  It sounds like you've described all three at various points in the comments.

Comment: Related issue discussed at [this blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/ssis-1/ole-db-source-date-literal). Summary: use `TO_DATE` or use Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

MSDAORA seems to be more intuitive with certain conversions while OraOLEDB.Oracle is more explicit.

So while MSDAORA will understand '01-JAN-2015' as a valid date when comparing to a date column, OraOLEDB.Oracle requires that the string be converted to a  date, for example to_date('01-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY').

TLDR:

```
Sql = "Select Count(*) from XYZ_DBO.TABLE_STATUS where BUSINESS_DATE='XXXXXXXX'"
```

Should become something like (depending on BUSINESS_DATE data type)

```
Sql = "Select Count(*) from XYZ_DBO.TABLE_STATUS where BUSINESS_DATE= to_date('XXXXXXXX','MMDDYYYY')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UseSessionFormat=True in connection string so it always use Oracle default date format.

connectionString = "PROVIDER=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Persist Security Info=True;UseSessionFormat=True;USER ID=XXXX;PASSWORD=XXXX;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXX)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXX)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))""